# Neutral and ground wires for ceiling fan wall control

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I am replacing a light fixture with a Craftmade ceiling fan ([https://www.amazon.com/Craftmade-TMPH44W5-Tempo-Ceiling-Remote/dp/B01D679HMA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01D679HMA)), operated by a wired remote control

I'm installing their wall remote control unit where the light fixture switch used to be. As per their diagram, I'm connecting the two black wires on the wall control unit to the two black wires in the box (one going to power supply, one to the fan).

Questions:

1. What to do with the two white neutral wires in the box (one from power supply and one leading to the fan) - do I connect them to each other or terminate both?
2. It appears that neither the outlet box in the ceiling nor the switch box are grounded (there is no third wire and nothing behind the box except wood and drywall, it's a pre-war building). If that's the case, should i still connect the ground wires from the fan motor and the wall unit to the boxes or would that actually make it even less safe?

Thank you in advance! [image: wiring diagram][image: wall control unit]

Comment: Does this Amazon Marketplace item have a proper UL listing?  There is a lot of unlisted Cheese junk running around Amazon Marketplace.  It matters because of the ground wire.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the two neutral wires in the back of the box provide the path back to the source for the current that powers your fan, so they need to stay nutted together or else the fan won't work.

The ground wires should be terminated to the box, though.  Some boxes are functionally grounded (via conduit or cable armor) even if there is no ground wire present, and I can't tell if yours are that way or not from here.